# Is <osx:NavigateToApp /> supported on IGoogle?

Tags: opensocial, igoogle

does not work in case of IGoogle/Gmail application but the same works on Orkut! My question is is it supported on IGoogle/Gmail?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No its not supported as of now!